# Converting string of decimal to list

Tags: c#, asp.net

When tring to convert string of decimal 
     "0,0,0,0,0,0,8555,127875,-180000,152000,55000,3.84,648000"
I get an error when one of the items is negative

Input string was not in a correct format.

```
System.Globalization.NumberStyles style = System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowThousands | System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowExponent ;
String t = "0,0,0,0,0,0,8555,127875,-180000,152000,55000,3.84,648000";
List<decimal> prices = t.Split(',').Select(n => decimal.Parse(n, style)).ToList();
```

Comment: So what do u want? You want that -ve one to convert to +ve, Ommit it or anything else??

Comment: I want the -180000 to one of the items in the list

Comment: Do you know why you're specifying `NumberStyles`?

Comment: Add  System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign flag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign flag.

```
System.Globalization.NumberStyles style = System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowThousands | System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowExponent | System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign;
String t = "0,0,0,0,0,0,8555,127875,-180000,152000,55000,3.84,648000";
List<decimal> prices = t.Split(',').Select(n => decimal.Parse(n, style)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String t = "0,0,0,0,0,0,8555,127875,-180000,152000,55000,3.84,648000";

String[] list = t.Split(',');
List<Decimal> decimals = new List<decimal>();
foreach (string s in list)
{
    decimals.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(s));
}
```

or

```
List<Decimal> decimals = t.Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ToDecimal(x)).ToList();
```